# PowerShell / Registry: Remove the "Activate Windows" watermark for Windows Sandbox

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, group-policy, windows-sandbox

The "Activate Windows" watermark is used by Microsoft to track unlicensed copies of Windows; this is important for them and I have no issue with that. However, for Windows Sandbox, we are aware that it is in a non-activated state but do not mind that (and from a logic perspective, there really is no *point* to the "Activate Windows" watermark here, because Windows Sandbox cannot exist outside of being a subservient component of a full Windows OS instance). Therefore, how can we completely suppress the "Activate Windows" watermark when working in Windows Sandbox (I would ideally like to be able to do this as a single silent set of PowerShell commands to put into my startup script)?

The following answer was not useful for this scenario: [How to Remove Windows Activation Watermark?](https://superuser.com/questions/1323717/how-to-remove-windows-activation-watermark)

I found the following registry snippet that purports to remove the watermark but have had no success (it may require a reboot; this might work by injecting into the registry of the VHDX from the host at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers\BaseImages\<GUID>\BaseLayer.vhdx`, but I'd rather avoid that if possible as that would be more complex).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\Activation]
"ActivationInterval"=dword:000dbba0
"Manual"=dword:00000001
"NotificationDisabled"=dword:00000000
```

I also found the following guide which I ran through in full, but it failed for Windows Sandbox

> regedit > Computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
> Panel\Desktop\PaintDesktopVersion Double click it and change the Value
> Data to 4
>
> Open CMD as Administrator gpupdate /force
>
> regedit >
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\svsvc On
> right, double-click Start and change the Value to 4. Right-click on a
> space on right side, select New. Select Key. Change its name to KMS.
>
> Double-click on the Default icon on the right side of the Window
> Change the Value to "kms_4" and OK that.
>
> Run "gpudate /force" on the Admin CMD again to update the Computer
> Policy.
>
> Start > Settings > look for notification: "Windows isn’t activated.
> Activate Windows now." Click on that and look for "Windows reported no
> product key was found on your device." To address this issue, take
> note of the Operating System Edition of your PC. Then, head to this
> link:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys
> Windows Sandbox always lists as "Enterprise"
> NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43 You can see all the keys on the
> Microsoft page that you will need to activate your Windows version.
> Scroll down until you see the Edition that matches the one that is on
> your PC.
>
> Get the entire key string and copy it. Open the Command Prompt again
> slmgr /ipk NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43 An error notification pops
> up, saying to run a command to see the error: slui.exe 0x2a 0xC0020036
> "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper" Then:
> slmgr /skms kms8.msguides.com then: slmgr /ato Both of these produce
> the same error ...
>
> Go back to the Settings Window and check if the Activation was
> successful. If you don’t see the red text anymore, then the method
> worked.  Go back to regedit > Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
> Panel\Desktop. On the right side Find PaintDesktopVersion and change
> the Value Data from 4 to 0.
>
> Finally, go back to the Admin CMD and type gpupdate /force This action
> will again Update your Computer Policy for the last time.
>
> Close all of the opened Windows. Right-click on your Desktop and hit
> Refresh. You should notice that the Windows 10 Watermark was removed.
>
> Take note that this solution only removes the Windows Activation
> watermark.

The above will remove the watermark without a reboot on a non-Sandbox system, but fails on the Sandbox. So, it looks like the elements are in place to be able to remove the watermark without a reboot with the right combination of commands. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try *Ease of Access Center > Make the computer easier to see*, click “Remove background images (where available),” and then Apply.

Comment: Will be great if this works, but I can't find that setting exactly. I've looked under Ease of Access, then searched all of the subheadings, then also tried typing "Remove background" into the search bar and nothing comes up. What specific subsection of Ease of Access do you see that setting under?

Comment: It is found in *Control Panel > Ease of Access Centre > Make the computer easier to see*.

Comment: Tried this now, and it failed to turn off the Windows Sandbox "Activiate Windows" watermark. Thanks for this suggestion though, it sounded ike it might work, but sadly does not.

Comment: See [this article](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/activate-windows-watermark/) - it has other methods (including my above one which didn't work).

Comment: I use SB daily, just not for long periods and I never see this watermark in any of my use cases to date. I cannot imagine a use case for all-day/everyday/regular use for it, but we all have our reasons. Anyway, see if these steps help. [3 Ways to Remove Activate Windows Watermark on Windows 10](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2020/12/10/remove-activate-windows-watermark-on-windows-10/)   ---   [How to Get Rid of the Activate Windows Watermark](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-rid-of-the-activate-windows-watermark-windows-10-pc-activation-message-removal/)

Comment: I keep my Sandboxes open for 3-4 days, often longer, at a time. A lot of people don't understand how useful Windows Sandbox containers are (there are reasons for this but they are just as useful as any full Docker setup; Windows Sandbox just need a bit more work to get there; there are very many use cases for this that I can show you if you are interested). Thanks for the links, I'll work through these also.

Comment: Sadly, none have worked so far (the `bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF` was new to me, but that gave an error `The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found.` Hopefully we can find a way. For sure, it is *just* an annoyance, but I feel that it's something that is an uneccessary inconvenience (i.e. it's not possible for someone to "pirate" a Sandbox, it's an appendage of the Host, and can't exist outside of that reality - hence, if the Host is activated, then the Sandbox should show that state also).